# Getting Extra Information From WinAPI File Change Notifications

Tags: winapi, filesystems, notifications, ntfs

The MSDN has a pretty good [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365261%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) of getting notified when a file or directory is changed.

However, I can't find any way to get extra information such as the user/machine name associated with the change notification.

For example, I've setup a share `X:\Foo` from my machine. I would like to log the user/machine names that make changes to my shared directory.

Is this possible to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You can't using FFCN.  You *can* set the security descriptor on the files in the shared directory to cause file accesses to be logged to the event log.

[This KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310399) has some information about how to enable auditing on files.